# Get previous intent name from Rasa action?

Tags: rasa-core

I have an intent called `intent_yes` which is shared in several different conversational flows. When the user says "Yes" or "Yeah" etc., it will call my webhook / Rasa action. I need to know *what* they've said yes to. How can we get the previous intent name from a Rasa webhook action?

Answer (score 5):

I think I agree with the OP. 
There are times, when an intent is activated for whole different reasons.

For instance, you have words like "Why?" "How?" for some specific intents, and their corresponding actions get triggered without discrimination. 
How do you prevent such basic expressions from being triggered in the most unlikely scenarios?

Surely it is not efficient to write stories for each conceivable conversational turns for "Why" & "How".

This is why I wanted a solution that checks the state of the conversation and determine if a particular intent has been triggered before running.

And Tom's solution above makes sense.
I will try that.

UPDATE:
This was my solution:

```
def get_latest_event(events)
  latest_actions = []
    for e in events:
        if e['event'] == 'action':
            latest_actions.append(e)

    return latest_actions[-2:][0]['name']

get_latest_event(tracker.events)
```

- I thought it best to wrap it in a function for portability.
- I init an empty list.
- Go through all the given events.
- If the event is an `action` event, I push it into the empty list above.
- I then return with the last two objects, pick the name of the first one.

The assumption is that we are looking for the last action that was triggered.

Again, my use-case is, I want a way to control my response to a generic follow-up question.

For instance, a user asks `why`?

I want to know the last thing the bot said (action) that triggers that `why`.

If it is an edge-case that I am interested in, I handle it differently.
If not, I respond generically.

Is this hacky?
Maybe.
But until I can figure out a way to prevent myself from writing stories for all possible ways a user can ask 'why?', this will do.
I am open to better suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not good design - you're better off writing individual stories for each flow and then having a corresponding action for each circumstance, however within the custom action's `run` method you can access the `tracker`.  This object holds all the events of the conversation in a list called `tracker.events`, which
will look something like this:

```
[{'event': 'action', 'timestamp': 1558688062.7624729, 'name': 'action_listen', 'policy': None, 'confidence': None},
{'event': 'user', 'timestamp': 1558688062.7628329, 'text': '/joke', 'parse_data': {'text': '/joke', 'intent': {'name': 'joke', 'confidence': 1.0}, 'intent_ranking': [{'name': 'joke', 'confidence': 1.0}], 'entities': []}, 'input_channel': 'rest'}]
```

To get the user messages just iterate backwards over this list until you find `"event":"user"` and the intent is given inside `"parse_data"["intent"]`